# Set PayPal CBT parameter in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal, return, customization

i'd like to customize the return button in PayPal and i've discovered that i have to set a parameter CBT in the request with the text of the button but i can't find how to do it in Magento (version 1.4.11).

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the answer by myself in this file

app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Standard/Redirect.php

after this loop:

```
foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
    $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));
}
```

i've added this line:

```
$form->addField("cbt", "hidden", array('name'=>'cbt', 'value' => 'YOUR MESSAGE'));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't forget that this is a core Magento change, and as such can potentially be overwritten with any Magento update.

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom field in your Paypal Standard follow the below steps:

**NOTE: Override the below mentioned files in your local and then do the changes. The core files mentioned are for path location only**

1) Open **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Standard.php** and under **protected $_globalMap** add your field after 'notify_url'

```
'cbt'    => 'cbt',
```

In the same file under **protected $_commonRequestFields** add after 'notify_url'

```
'cbt'
```

2) Open **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php** and under **public function getStandardCheckoutFormFields()** add

```
$api->setOrderId($orderIncrementId)
            ->setCurrencyCode($order->getBaseCurrencyCode())
            //->setPaymentAction()
            ->setOrder($order)
            ->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/ipn/'))
            ->setReturnUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/standard/success'))
            ->setCbt('your_cbt_value') // set your value here
            ->setCancelUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/standard/cancel'));
```

This will result in below form code

```
<input id="cbt" name="cbt" value="your_cbt_value" type="hidden"/>
```